# add_filter only to a specific Custom post templates

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-hook

I have many custom post templates.
I need to apply an "add_filter" only to one of those.

May I put the "add_filter_ cod directly on custom post template page?
In functions.php I have to filer by custom post templates name but I can't find how to get it.

Comment: Check this out: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238640/what-does-is-page-template-compare-against

Comment: That's the correct answer you should add it as an answer.